# MVC Controller Indexing decimal

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database

Hope you can help me with the following problem. I am working with the controller part to upload multiple records to the database. However I have a problem with the indexing `[i]` (`INDX.Ratio`).

This is my controller code:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index_Ratio_Save(FormCollection C)
    {
        int i = 0;

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var IDArray = C.GetValues("item.ID");
            var CountryArray = C.GetValues("item.Country");
            var FormatArray = C.GetValues("item.Format");
            decimal RatioArray = Convert.ToDecimal(C.GetValues("item.Ratio"));

            for (i = 0; i < IDArray.Count(); i++) 
            {
                C_004_Index_Ratio INDX = dbcloud.C_004_Index_Ratio.Find(Convert.ToInt32(IDArray[i]));
                INDX.Country = CountryArray[i];
                INDX.Format = FormatArray[i];
                INDX.Ratio = RatioArray[i];

                dbcloud.Entry(INDX).State = EntityState.Modified;
            }

            dbcloud.SaveChanges();
        }

        return View();
    }
```

The `INDX.Ratio = RatioArray[i]` is giving me the following error:

> Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'decimal'

I think I am almost there, do you know how to fix this?

### UPDATE:

Model:

```
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Format { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> Ratio { get; set; }
```

Comment: `RatioArray` is `decimal`, so.. What do you think you will get when you do `RatioArray[i]`?

Comment: I was thinking it would post every changed record from the view. However the problem is that RatioArray is a decimal, which is providing the error.   I will update the answer with the model also.

Comment: index is only int based you can't use fractional values

Comment: so how would i be able to post the ratio part? any suggestions?

Comment: Perhaps you should learn the basics of MVC model binding and use stongly typed html helpers to generate your view so that you can post back to a model - `public ActionResult SaveIEnumerable<YourModel model)`

Answer (score 2):

RatioArray is not an array, you are defining it as an single item.  It would need to be defined like this:

```
decimal[] RatioArray = ...
```

The problem here, however, is that your code to retrieve the items from the FormsCollection will not work this way.  You are only converting a single item because `Convert.ToDecimal()` only works on a single item.

You would want to do something like this:

```
 decimal[] RatioArray = Array.ConvertAll(c.GetValues("item.Ratio"), double.Parse);
```

Looking at your model, it doesn't look like your model supports an array either.  So it looks like your problem may be a lot bigger than just this issue.

You really should just be using model binding, however, since then you get this functionality automatically, and you get validation support.

Answer (score 0):

I appears from you POST method that your view is rendering a collection of objects and your using a `foreach` loop to render the controls resulting in non-indexed `name` attributes which cant be bound a collection (and probably invalid html as a result of duplicate `id` attributes). Instead, make use of MVC's built in model binding features so that you can POST back and bind to your model, for example

View

```
@model IList<YourModel>
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
  for(int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
  {
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].ID)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].Country)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].Format)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].Ratio)   
  }
  <input type="submit" />
}
```

This will generate property named inputs with indexers for binding

```
<input type="hidden" name="[0].ID" ...>
<input type="hidden" name="[0].Country" ...>
....
<input type="hidden" name="[1].ID" ...>
<input type="hidden" name="[1].Country" ...>
....
```

Then change the controller to

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index_Ratio_Save(IEnumerable<YourModel> model)
```

and the model will be correctly bound to the collection. Note an alternative to using a `for` loop is to create a custom `EditorTemplate` for the object

/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/YourModel.cshtml

```
@Model YourModel
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ID)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Country)
...
```

and in the view

```
@model IEnumerable<YourModel>
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.EditorFor(m => m)
  <input type="submit" />
}
```

which generates the same html (allows the collection to be `IEnumerable` rather than `IList`